# join more than 2 sql tables without ignoring rows whitch have null colomn

Tags: php, mysql, sql

am trying to make sql query witch join more than 2 sql tables without ignoring rows whitch have null values

this is my query

```
SELECT d.id, d.nbPieces, o.title, o.latitude, o.longitude, p.link, v.nom
FROM operation o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     disponible d
     ON d.numOperation = o.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     photooperation p
     ON o.id = p.numoperation , city v 
WHERE d.nbPieces = 1
            AND (d.surfaceMin>=8 AND d.surfaceMax<=300)
            AND (d.prixMin>=140000 AND d.prixMax<=3500000) 
            AND v.id = o.numCity
```

the link column can be null for somme rows

result should look like:

```
id    nbPieces    title   latitude    longitude    link        nom

1     5           title1  -9.3564565  33.654864    photo1.jpg  newYork
2     5           title2  -3.3564565  45.6584566   NULL        Tokio
3     5           title3  -2.3564565  13.6548786   NULL        Frence
```

thankyou

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`. But you already using it. So what is the problem than?

Comment: something is not correct in my query, it give me some row without link values, but they have it (there is a foreign key references operation table in the photooperation table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Then, you simply need to move the `WHERE` conditions on all but the first table into the `ON` clauses:

```
SELECT d.id, d.nbPieces, o.title, o.latitude, o.longitude, p.link, v.nom
FROM operation o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     disponible d
     ON d.numOperation = o.id AND
        (d.surfaceMin >= 8 AND d.surfaceMax <= 300) AND
        (d.prixMin >= 140000 AND d.prixMax <= 3500000) AND
        d.nbPieces = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     photooperation p
     ON o.id = p.numoperation LEFT OUTER JOIN
     city v 
     ON v.id = o.numCity;
```

Comment: What is the difference where you put your conditions? In `WHERE` or in `ON` part?

Comment: this query return some rows where id is null, but i don't have null id in my table disponible, it should give also rows where link is null

Comment: id           nbPieces          title   latitude    longitude    link        nom

NULL    NULL         title1  -9.3564565  33.654864    photo1.jpg  newYork
NULL    NULL         title2  -3.3564565  45.6584566   NULL        Tokio
3           5                title3  -2.3564565  13.6548786   NULL        Frence

Comment: thank you @Gordon Linoff it was just essue of join ordre. am going to accept your answer